# Data success then "URL key for specified store already exists" error

Tags: error, import

[image: success report]

[image: error report]

Having received 100% success, ready for import, the next page then denies the upload, why? I have tried making the document smaller, only 700 entries, but receive the same OK then the same error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a version issue, I bet.  Could you specify which version of Magento you are using.

For example, this will describe some resolutions released in 2.1.8 that may be what you need:

> **Import/Export**
>
> We’ve fixed an issue where product URL keys (for SKUs) were not auto-generated as expected during import.

More details:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8CE.html#importexport

**More potential resolutions**

In 2.1.3 CE Release notes:

> Magento now removes category URL keys from the url_rewrite table as expected during import. Previously, Magento did not remove these keys, which triggered a failure during import. This subsequently caused Magento to quickly reach the maximum error count, returning this error: “Maximum error count has been reached or system error is occurred!”. (GITHUB-1471)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.3CE.html

**UPDATE**

I just noticed you are showing version **2.1.12** ...  Perhaps, check to see if any code from older core was retained throughout the upgrades?